# jqplot in CakePHP not rendering for unknown reason

Tags: php, html, cakephp, jqplot

I have a CakePHP site and wish to render jqplots on the fly. At the moment I am unable to render anything at all...

In my default layout I have:

```
// ../layouts/default.ctp
echo $this->Html->script('jquery');
echo $this->Html->script('jquery.jqplot.min');
echo $this->Html->css('jquery.jqplot.min');
```

When I view the source, all these files are available to the browser (i.e. I can click on each of the src links and it pulls the file just fine).

In my View file:

```
// ..Views/Plots/index.ctp
<div id="mychart" style="height:400px;width:500px; "></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.jqplot('mychart', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);
    });
</script>
```

When I view the source, everything is displayed in the correct place i.e. scripts in the `<head>` section, and the view sits nicely inside my `#content` div. What the hell am I doing wrong?! Been tearing my hair out for the past three hours!

Comment: I have jqPlot in my Cake app working just fine, so it is possible. By default the css file is name `jquery.jqplot.css` though and not `jquery.jqplot.min.css` as you're trying to load. Did you rename that file or might that be the mistake?

Comment: Nothing seems to work. @Oldskool - I'd be really grateful if you could verify where your files are lying in your `app/webroot` directory so I can be certain I'm not doing something really silly.

Comment: All my CSS is under `app/webroot/css/jquery.jqplot.css` (non-minified) and my JS files are collected under `app/webroot/js/jqplot/*.js` and the plugins are under `plugins` within that folder.

Comment: I've managed to get it working by using the version of jquery included with jqplot (v1.6.4). My version (v1.9.0) appeared to be causing the error. Either that or something weird was happening with my CakePHP cache. Anyway, it's working now. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED**

Problem appeared to be with the version of jquery I was using. I am now using the version of jquery that was included with jqplot (v1.6.4).